# Prove $\sin^3A-\cos^3A=\left(\sin^2A-\cos^2A\right)(1-2\sin^2A\cos^2A)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $\sin^3A-\cos^3A=\left(\sin^2A-\cos^2A\right)(1-2\sin^2A\cos^2A)$

My attempt is as follows:

Taking LHS:

$$\left(\sin A-\cos A\right)(1+\sin A\cos A)$$
$$\left(\sin^2A-\cos^2A\right)\frac{\left(1+\sin A\cos A\right)}{\left(\sin A+\cos A\right)}$$
$$\left(\sin^2A-\cos^2A\right)\frac{(\left(\sin A+\cos A\right)^2-\sin A\cos A)}{\sin A+\cos A}$$
$$\left(\sin^2A-\cos^2A\right)\left(\sin A+\cos A-\frac{\sin A\cos A}{\sin A+\cos A}\right)$$

I was not getting any breakthroughs from here.

So I tried RHS:

$$(\sin A-\cos A)(\sin A+\cos A)(1-2\sin^2A\cos^2A)$$
$$(\sin A-\cos A)(\sin A+\cos A)((\sin^2A+\cos^2A)^2-2\sin^2A\cos^2A)$$
$$(\sin A-\cos A)(\sin A+\cos A)(\sin^4A+\cos^4A)$$

Even from here I was not getting breakthroughs, what am i missing?

Please help me.

Comment: Hint:$$\sin^3A-\cos^3A=\sin^3A-\sin^2A\cos A+\sin^2A\cos A-\sin A\cos^2A+\sin A\cos^2A-\cos^3A$$
$$=\sin^2A(1-\cos A)+\sin A\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)-\cos^2A(1-\sin A)$$

Comment: this expression is also not leading anywhere, I tried it

Comment: please see what I have done in my attempt in the question

Answer (score 2):

With $x=\pi$ the LHS is equal to $1$ while the RHS is equal to $-1$ therefore the identity is false.

Answer (score 0):

$(\sin^2A-\cos^2A)(1-\sin^2A\cos^2A)$
$=(\sin A-\cos A)(\sin A+\cos A)(\sin^4A+\cos^4A).$

But I think the problem is wrong, just try with $A=\frac{\pi}{5}$.